# Do loop not running the If clause

Tags: algorithm

My full code is a bit more complicated but I hope that this works as a minimal example.

```
      Implic[c_, G_, yi_, y_, n_, q_, beta_, r_, p_, d_] := c - q
    Seco[c_, G_, yi_, y_, n_, q_, beta_, r_, p_, d_] := r - beta
    Ass1[c_, q_, p_, d_] := - p d Log[q]/c
    ySQ[c_, G_, y_, n_, q_, beta_, r_, p_, d_] := 
     1 - (- p d Log[q]/ n /c  (2 - 1/n))^(-1)
    Z = 0; 
     Do[ Do[ Do[ Do[ Do[ Do[ Do[ Do[
            If[Z == 0, If[Ass1[c, q, p, d] > 1, 
                
              If[Ass1[c, G, ySQ[c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d], y, q, beta, 
                 r, p, d] > 1, 
                                  
               nopt = n /. 
                 FindRoot[
                  Ass1[c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d]/n - 
                   Log[(Ass1[c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d]/n)*(2 - 
                        1/n)]/(1 - ((Ass1[c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d]/
                        n)*(2 - 1/n))^(-1)), {n, 1}], 
                                  
               If[Implic[c, G, ySQ[c, G, y, nopt, q, beta, r, p, d], y, 
                  nopt, q, beta, r, p, d] < 0,
                 
                If[Seco[c, G, ySQ[c, G, y, nopt, q, beta, r, p, d], y, 
                   nopt, q, beta, r, p, d] < 0,
 H = {c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d},
                                    Z = Z + 1]]]]]
            , {c, 0.1, 5, 1}]
           , {G, 1, 10, 3}]
          , {y, 0.01, 1, 0.3}]
         , {q, 0.01, 1, 0.3}]
        , {beta, 0.1, 2, 0.6}]
       , {r, 0.1, 2, 0.6}]
      , {p, 0.1, 10, 3}]
     , {d, 0.1, 10, 3}]
    Z
```

I am pretty sure that my mistake is somewhere in the If clause but I do not see where. If I remove the If clauses and just run Z=Z+1 the code works.
Do I need to use semicolon instead of comma somewhere?
Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call `ySQ[c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d]` does not match the function pattern

```
ySQ[c_, G_, y_, n_, q_, beta_, r_, p_, d_]
```

so `nopt` never gets set.

---

FYI this was discovered by using the following debugging additions:

```
...
Z = 0;

whatisit = {};
hit1 = hit2 = False;

Do[Do[Do[Do[Do[Do[Do[Do[
        AppendTo[whatisit, {c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d, Z}]; 
        If[Z == 0, If[Ass1[c, q, p, d] > 1,
          hit1 = True;
          If[Ass1[c, G, ySQ[c, G, y, q, beta, r, p, d], y, q, beta, r, p, d] > 1,
           hit2 = True;
           nopt = n /. FindRoot[ etc. ...
```

Observing that `hit2` never got set True I ran `Ass1` over `whatisit`

```
Ass1[#1,#2, ySQ[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8], #3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8] & @@@ whatisit
```

> {Ass1[0.1, 1, ySQ[0.1, 1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 0.01, 0.01,
> 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
> Ass1[1.1, 1, ySQ[1.1, 1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 0.01, 0.01,
> 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
> Ass1[2.1, 1, ySQ[2.1, 1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 0.01, 0.01,
> 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], ...

where it was quickly apparent that `ySQ` was not being evaluated.

Comment: I've run the new "analyze notebook" on the code, and it did not see this signature mismatch.  One would think that "analyze notebook" should detect such things!  V 13.1